# c++ вычислить значение выражения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, ряды

Во входном потоке задано три вещественных числа a (a > 0), b (b < 0), x (-1 < x < 1). Значения исходных данных подобраны так, что выражение имеет смысл.
например, 2.4 -4.2 0.6

В выходной поток вывести единственное вещественное число с точностью три знака после запятой.
например, 2.425

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код, для значений из примера работает верно, но если x поменять на 0.5, то выводит ошибку (-nan).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  double a,b,x,p,sum=0;
  cin >> a >> b >> x;
  if ((1.2+8*x)<105)
  {
    for (double m=(8*x+1.2);m<=105.0;m++)
    {
      sum+=(pow((-1),m)*m+a)/(m*(m+1));
    }
  }
  p=(x-b)/(a+b);
  p=pow(p,3);
  p=sin(p)/cos(p);
  p=pow(p,3)*sum;
  p=p+(pow((x+pow(a,2)),1.0/2.0))/(x*pow((1-b),1.0/3.0));
  cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << p;
}
```

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидаете в этом случае? по условию `b` должно быть меньше нуля

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас получается возведение отрицательного числа в дробную степень

```
pow((-1),m)
```

при вашем значении `x`. У вас именно исходя из этого - наличия `-1` в степени `m` эта переменная не может быть `double`, а вычисления должны проводиться при условии

> Значения исходных данных подобраны так, что выражение имеет смысл

которое вы нарушили.

Впрочем, считать сумму таким образом - не то чтобы совсем некорректно... но ужасно некрасиво.

P.S. Для тангенса есть своя функция - `tan()`.

P.P.S. Ваш ряд я бы считал иначе -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, но что мне следует заменить?

Comment: Ну не нарывайтесь на грубый ответ, а? :) В вашей программе - значение x такое, чтобы 1.2+8x было целым числом (как минимум). Вас (увы, и не только вас) не интересует **понять**, вас интересует только **сдать**... :(